# Using protobuf-java in GraalVM native image

Tags: java, graalvm, protobuf-java

Trying to convert existing Spring Boot micro-service to run on GraalVM native image came across an issue with protobuf generated classed with protobuf-java.

Generated classes use reflection and need to add ALL classes to reflect-config.json, also many classes has nested Builder classes so need to add of these as well, very dirty work for existing projects having hundreds of such protos.

Reading protobuf [documentation](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/jvm_aot.md) it is mentioned either use [protobuf-javalite](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/java/lite.md) or run [GraalVM tracing agent](https://www.graalvm.org/jdk17/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/) to generate reflect-config.json automatically.

Moving to protobuf-javalite sounds risky, it was designed for Android and advertised as not stable library.

Running trace agent after every modification of proto add major overhead to development process.

So the question if anyone came across same issue and was able to solve that in more elegant manner and if there are any [better plans](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6497) of protobuf-java to support native image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above solution is great for applications not using Spring Boot.
Following similar logic, I created similar solution for [Spring Boot context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints).

Dependency in addition to spring boot 3.1.3+ depedencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.Scanners;
import org.springframework.aot.hint.ExecutableMode;
import org.springframework.aot.hint.RuntimeHints;
import org.springframework.aot.hint.RuntimeHintsRegistrar;

import com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3;
import com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ProtobufRuntimeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {
    
    private static final String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_FILENAME = "META-INF/native-image/protobuf-packages.properties";

    @Override
    public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hint, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            
        // packages from file
        Set<String> packagesToScan = null;
        try {
             packagesToScan = loadPackagesToScan();
            logInfo("Loaded packages to scan:\n" + packagesToScan);         
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load packages to scan", e);
        }
        
        // register
        for (String packageName : packagesToScan) {
            registerGrpcClassesFromReflection(hint, packageName);
        }
    }
    
    private Set<String> loadPackagesToScan() throws IOException {
        
        InputStream stream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_FILENAME);
        
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Resource not found: " + PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_FILENAME);
        }
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(stream);
        return props.stringPropertyNames();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static void registerGrpcClassesFromReflection(RuntimeHints hint, String packageName) {

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, Scanners.SubTypes);
        Set<Class<? extends GeneratedMessageV3>> messageClasses = 
                    reflections.getSubTypesOf(GeneratedMessageV3.class);
        Set<Class<? extends GeneratedMessageV3.Builder>> builderClasses = 
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(GeneratedMessageV3.Builder.class);
        Set<Class<? extends ProtocolMessageEnum>> enums = 
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(ProtocolMessageEnum.class);       
        
        Set<Class<?>> classesToBeRegistered = new HashSet<>();
        classesToBeRegistered.addAll(messageClasses);
        classesToBeRegistered.addAll(builderClasses);
        classesToBeRegistered.addAll(enums);
        
        logInfo("Registering package [" + packageName + "], classes [" + classesToBeRegistered.size() + "]");
        for (Class<?> clazz : classesToBeRegistered) {
            registerClass(hint, clazz);
        }
    }
    
    private static void registerClass(RuntimeHints hints, Class<?> clazz) {
        
        String className = clazz.getName();
        try {
            // register class
            hints.reflection().registerType(clazz);
            
            // register all methods
            int methodsCount = 0;
            for (java.lang.reflect.Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
                hints.reflection().registerMethod(method, ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
                methodsCount++;
            }

            logInfo("Registered class: [" + className + "], methods [" + methodsCount + "]");

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            logError("Failed to register class: [" + className + "] " + re.getMessage());
        }       
    }
    
    private static void logInfo(String msg) {
        msg = "ProtobufReflectionHints: " + msg;
        log.info(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private static void logError(String msg) {
        msg = "ProtobufReflectionHints: " + msg;
        log.error(msg);
        System.err.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Add to Spring @Configuration class:

```
@ImportRuntimeHints(ProtobufRuntimeHints.class)
```

Resource file (`META-INF/native-image/protobuf-packages.properties`):

```
the.package.to.scan
```

Test:

```
@Test
void shouldRegisterHints() {
    RuntimeHints hints = new RuntimeHints();
    new ProtobufRuntimeHints().registerHints(hints, getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

Comment: Just tested this on Spring Boot 3.2.0 project, works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the most convenient way in this case is to create custom feature (described [here](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/Reflection/#configuration-with-features)) which scans classpath before analysis and register the classes for runtime reflection.

Created simple utility which do that for you. You just need to add it as dependency into your project

https://github.com/ricantech/protobuf-graalvm-feature

Comment: Thanks, will take a look, I guess it scans specific packages only of protobuff generated classes, otherwise we dismiss the benefits of native-image to pack into executable only required classes. Did you consider to raise enhancement for protobuf-java to provide such utility ?

Comment: Hi, yes, It can be configured to scan only relevant packages or grab every class which extends protbuf base classes.
I'm thinking of raising the enhancement for protobuf, but yet haven't had time to go through the open issues to see where I could raise it or whether I need to create the new issue.

Comment: I found only one relevant issue which was closed with documentation update, not very helpful other than be aware about that limitation. https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6497

Comment: You need to include classes for enums. Set<Class<? extends ProtocolMessageEnum>> enums = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ProtocolMessageEnum.class);

Comment: Its part of 1.0.1. Please give it a try